# Dynamic configuration for @Scheduled in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, spring-scheduled

I'm trying to dynamically configure a Spring Boot schedule using the configuration file.

The goal is to have the following in my `application.yml`:

```
platform:
  plata:
    schedule:
      cron: '0 0 9 * * *'
  platb:
    schedule:
      initialDelay = 20000
      fixedDelay = 10000000
```

What I'm struggling with, is how I can now apply this configuration to the `@Scheduled` annotations. I was thinking something like the following:

`Scheduler.java:`

```
@Scheduled("${platform.plata.schedule}")
public void plata() throws CalculationException {
    ...
}

@Scheduled("${platform.platb.schedule}")
public void platb() throws CalculationException {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You probably would do better in configuring the scheduler programmatically: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler Would this be an option for you?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli: Thanks for the suggestion, but  unfortunately this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use full path of property in your configuration.

Corn expression should be `0 0 9 * * *` note no **'**-chars

```
@Scheduled(cron="${platform.plata.schedule.cron}")
public void withCron() {
    // 
}

@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${platform.platb.schedule.initialDelay}" ,fixedDelayString= "${platform.platb.schedule.fixedDelay}")
public void withFixedDelay() {
    // 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm sorry it was not clear from my question, but what I'm looking for is that I can change from cron to `initialDelay` and `fixedDelay` in the config file without changing the code. That's why I'm looking to inject a something like a Map into `@Scheduled`.